# How to skip "Select Certification Authority" dialog with PowerShell scripting?

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, x509, certificate-authority

I am issuing X.509 certificates using a PowerShell (4.0) script. Besides other lines here are the lines related to this issue:

```
certreq -new "$INFPath" "$CSRPath"
certreq -submit "$CSRPath" "$CERPath"
```

When I run the script, there is a "Select Certification Authority" dialog with every certificate that I have to click manually:

[image: Select Certification Authority]

Is there a way to skip this dialog? I could not find any related parameter for the command nor found I CmndLets that may have such features which are similar to the commands.

Comment: Try the -config option. From the CertReq page (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296456(v=ws.11).aspx) "Processes the operation by using the CA specified in the configuration string, which is CAHostName\CAName. For an https connection, specify the enrollment server URI. For the local machine store CA, use a minus (-) sign. For example -config ca1.timhaintz.com\ca1

Comment: @TimHaintz, please make and answer - you are correct

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for letting me know burnersk. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the -config option.

From the CertReq [page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296456(v=ws.11).aspx).

"Processes the operation by using the CA specified in the configuration string, which is CAHostName\CAName. For an https connection, specify the enrollment server URI. For the local machine store CA, use a minus (-) sign."

For example:

```
certreq -new "$INFPath" "$CSRPath"
certreq -submit "$CSRPath" "$CERPath" -config ca1.timhaintz.com\ca1
```

Thanks, Tim.

Answer (score 3):

I've got this error with this command:

> "Certificate Request Processor: The directory name is invalid. 0x8007010b (WIN32/HTTP: 267)"

to make it work I do it like this:

`certreq -submit -config ca1.timhaintz.com\ca1 "$CSRPath" "$CERPath"`